# How to find intersection points of two SVG shapes using d3.js

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, d3.js

I have two SVG shapes (line and spiral path ) which intersect each other at multiple points. I want to find all the intersection points of these SVG shapes using d3.js. Also I need to achieve this without using any third party package like kld-intersection, etc.

Below is the code for both the svg shapes :

```css
.cls-3 {
                fill: none;
                stroke-width: 10px;
                stroke: #000;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
            }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1031.1 1010.3" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <title>SVG Shapes</title>
            <g id="Spiral_Path">
                <path class="cls-3 svg-range-line"
                    d="M881.5,154.9C679.6-47,352.3-47,150.4,154.9c-195.9,195.9-195.9,513.4,0,709.3,189.7,190,497.5,190.1,687.5.4l.4-.4c184.3-184.3,184.3-483,0-667.3h0C659.6,18.1,369.8,18.1,191.1,196.8H191C17.6,370.3,17.6,651.4,191,824.8" />
<line stroke="red" x1="486.5027" y1="501.64715" x2="-220.59908118654766" y2="-205.45963118654743"></line>
</svg>
```

Comment: Break the path up into its individual ellipsis, iterate over those, testing for ellipsis-line intersection. While finding ellipsis-line intersection is known, translating SVG-style arc notation to something useful for the calculations is likely to be tedious.

Comment: Have you seen this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/bricof/f1f5b4d4bc02cad4dea454a3c5ff8ad7)?